# How do I participate on Blog Overflow?

Tags: support, blog-overflow

My site has gone and [created a blog](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/). We've discussed it on meta, and now I'd like to contribute to it.

If I want to contribute a post, where do I send it for review?

If I'm an editor (following the aforementioned discussion), what should I do? Where do I receive posts to edit, how do I discuss things with the author and potential contributors, how do I push a post through?

Comment: I sent an email to one of the guys who looked in charge, and that worked for me.

Comment: On Cross-Validated (the stat site) we have a chat room dedicated to the blog.  You could try creating a similar one on U/L.

Comment: I'm one of the “guys who look in charge” (this is for [SFF](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/632/lets-get-the-blog-going) where I'm something like editor-in-second, but I figure others are wondering the same thing), and I can't find any information on the specifics. I gather the answer for contributors is to see with your site's editors, but what are editors to do?

Comment: True, there is no obvious way to get involved.  Good question.  That's why my answer was so informal.

Answer (score 3):

On SU & Gaming we have chat rooms set up to discuss any matters related to the blog.

Mostly anyone who's interested in writing (and has a certain measure of trust/rep on the main site) get's **an Author account**. That means they can upload an post, but can't publish it themselves. They can mark their post as **Pending Review** to indicate its ready for publishing, but most of the time they would let the **Editors or users in charge** know its ready in the chatroom.

Another useful tool is setting up a shared Google Docs ([link to SU's outdated version](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zxXAhNdlgRXNAWdlpn1M9O_dfgkO366frodssCTjAts/edit?hl=en_US&authkey=CP-v0agK)), where you can try to plan ahead slightly and keep track of topics you might want to blog about. Yes you can use stars on chat or Meta, but a Google Docs is more flexible.

It would be helpful to have something similar to the Open Source Ads on the main sites on the blog, that linked to the About and Contribute page. That way any users that wanders into the blog  would have an idea where to go if they want to contribute. Even on SU we have trouble getting across that any user that has something interesting to share **could get his posts published**...